# Image recognition C++ API

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I have problem with this tutorial:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_recognition

I took all the steps but when i try run this command:

```
bazel build tensorflow/examples/label_image/...
```

ERROR: Skipping 'tensorflow/examples/label_image/...': no targets found beneath 'tensorflow/examples/label_image'

But this work:

```
bazel build tensorflow/examples/label_image/data
```

and this create a 5 folders (bazel-bin, bazel-data, bazel-genfiles, bazel-out, bazel- testlogs). But every folder is empty.

I can't run this command:

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image
```

Comment: Try running `bazel build tensorflow/examples/label_image:label_image` and then `bazel run tensorflow/examples/label_image:label_image`.

Comment: I try but ERROR: Skipping 'tensorflow/examples/label_image:label_image': no such package 'tensorflow/examples/label_image': BUILD file not found on package path

Comment: can you confirm that there is a `BUILD` file in `tensorflow/examples/label_image/`? According to [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image) repo, there is.

Comment: It's missing. I added and work. But new error here: ERROR: Analysis of targret '//tensorflow/examples/label_image:label_image_py' failed; build aborted: Loading failed.

Comment: that just seems like a common error in your `BUILD` file

Comment: How to fix it? I use same file like in github.

Comment: what is the full error message?

Comment: This: http://img.tpx.cz/uploads/Sn%C3%ADmek%20obrazovky%20po%C5%99%C3%ADzen%C3%BD%202018-02-11%2014-57-34.png

Comment: Did you run the `configure` script?